# How to create global filter search with redux toolkit, react and javascripr?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, redux-toolkit

I need to develop a global search filter to search the products based on the product title.

To solve the problem I'm using redux to manage the global formal state. I created a reducer to filter the titles, however, I don't know how to get the array of API objects and play in the initialState data: []; To call the API I'm using createAPI from the redux toolkit.

Some part of code:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name: "search",
  initialState: {
    data: [], // array of objects from API
    filteredTitle: [],
    isLoading: true
  },
  reducers: {
    getData: (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
    searchByName: (state, action) => {
      const filteredResult = state.data.filter((product) =>
        product.title.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase())
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredTitle:
          action.payload.length > 0 ? filteredResult : [...state.data]
      };
    }
  }
});

export const { searchByName, getData } = searchSlice.actions;
export default searchSlice.reducer;
```

In App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { searchByName, getData } from "./features/slice";
import { useGetAllProductsQuery } from "./services/api";

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const filteredTitle = useSelector((state) => state.search.filteredTitle);
  const [searchTerm, setSearch] = useState("");
  const { data } = useGetAllProductsQuery();

  console.log("data", data);

  const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(searchByName(searchTerm));
    dispatch(getData(data));
  }, [searchTerm, dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={changeSearchTerm} type="text" value={searchTerm} />
      <div>
        {filteredTitle.map((user) => (
          <div>{user.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-fog-fsbnkd?file=/src/features/slice.js:0-732)

Answer (score 0):

`Redux Toolkit Query` is made, so you won't interact with Redux store with thunk functions directly (that's what they say in their documentation).
You can only use `transformResponse` once creating the query. I haven't come across any ways, to be able to add an extra reducer to the slices that are made with `RTK Query`.

The first way, is to store the data that you are getting from the query, inside another `slice`, and then use a reducer to filter your data.

The [second way](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) is to create a `slice`, and using `createAsyncThunk`, fetch your data, then treat your data as you want it. I can leave an example for you:

```
export const getName = createAsyncThunk('getNameFromBE',
    async name => {
    await fetch('https://example.com/studentID)
    }
)

export const studnetSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'studentSlice',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
          aReducer : (state, action) => {state.name = action.payload}
    },
    extraReducers: {
          [getName .pending]: state => {
            state.loading = true
            state.failed = false
         },
          [getName .fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.name= action.payload
            state.loading = false
         },
          [getName .rejected]: state => {
            state.loading = false
            state.rejected = true
         },
      }
    })
```

Here you have  a slice, with thunk and normal reducers, with a state that is accessible, but the downside is that you have to manage `fetch` completely manually (can be an advantage too), and also the call state (pending, fulfilled, rejected) must be done manually, which takes a lot of boilerplate code writing.